# Google Cloud Dataflow - Read in pubsub message as String

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

Is there a way to receive a message from pubsub in Java code and then turn that code into a String of some sort to be parsed for which can then be used as input variables in code?

I have retrieved the pubsub message using PubSubIO, However I only know how to get it as a PCollection of Strings or as a side input using views, however I cannot find anyway to get an actual string out of this data for use in the Java code.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, this is not possible. It's not possible to use the value of an element from the `PCollection` outside of the definition of the `Pipeline`. Intuitively, it seems like this is possible when writing the Java code (possibly no compilation errors), but this is not how Apache Beam actually works. I imagine you'd get some kind of runtime/serialization error during execution.

Presumably, you want to use some value of an element to alter the `Pipeline`. In this case, you'd need to know all of the possible values ahead of time in order to partition/construct the `Pipeline`; the values need to be predetermined.

Comment: Okay, basically what I am trying to do is  allow someone to send a PubSub message and read that in through the pipeline, and then parse it to use whats in the PubSub message in code, there is no way to read in a PubSub message outside the pipeline either I guess so there really is no way to do this?

Comment: Correct. I don't think there is a way to use the value of the PubSub message in the code itself. For further clarification, you can use the value of the PubSub message inside a transform for example, but that is within the definition of the `Pipeline`.

Comment: A Pipeline is like an execution plan. PCollection's do not contain elements - they simply describe an intermediate node in the execution plan, saying "at execution time, this is the type of data that will flow through this node". By constructing the pipeline, you construct the execution plan, which can then be kicked off for actual execution via p.run(). If you want to apply custom code to elements of PCollections, why not just use a ParDo within your pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but what exactly is the problem? Yes, PubsubIO.readStrings() will produce a PColleciton of Strings, not Strings per se, but the next transform that will be chained to this one will receive those Strings, so you can easily apply JAVA code to each of them there using ProcessContext.element() within the @ProcessElement function of that transform. That's where you do all your splitting/etc. Is that what you are after?